# How to implement this cupertino picker

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter. I am trying to implement the number picker like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSntk.png)

but I am not able to implement it with number picker.

How to implement this using cupertino picker or any other alternative ?
Can anyone give me basic idea of how to do it ? I will customize it later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide selectionOverlay to CupertinoPicker something like

`selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDividerSelectionOverlay(),`

I have made changes to the default selection overlay class provided with flutter to achieve the result you are looking for

```dart
class CupertinoPickerDividerSelectionOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  const CupertinoPickerDividerSelectionOverlay({
    super.key,
    this.background = CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
    this.capStartEdge = true,
    this.capEndEdge = true,
  });

  /// Whether to use the default use rounded corners and margin on the start side.
  final bool capStartEdge;

  /// Whether to use the default use rounded corners and margin on the end side.
  final bool capEndEdge;

  /// The color to fill in the background of the [CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay].
  /// It Support for use [CupertinoDynamicColor].
  ///
  /// Typically this should not be set to a fully opaque color, as the currently
  /// selected item of the underlying [CupertinoPicker] should remain visible.
  /// Defaults to [CupertinoColors.tertiarySystemFill].
  final Color background;

  /// Default margin of the 'SelectionOverlay'.
  static const double _defaultSelectionOverlayHorizontalMargin = 9;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
        start: capStartEdge ? _defaultSelectionOverlayHorizontalMargin : 0,
        end: capEndEdge ? _defaultSelectionOverlayHorizontalMargin : 0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.symmetric(
            horizontal: BorderSide(
                color: CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(background, context),
                width: 2)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```